# CMake: Using add_custom_command with TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS when it might be empty

Tags: windows, cmake

In my CMakeLists, I have the following code:

```
if (WIN32)

  add_custom_command(TARGET MyExe POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:MyExe> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyExe>
    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
  )
endif()
```

which works smoothly 99% of the time. However, in some configurations, i.e. using a static build of the libraries, the $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:MyExe> generator expression evaluates to an empty string and the command fails with a cryptic message. How can I perform a check beforehand? I am very confused by generator expressions and from what I understand, they can only be used in certain commands.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cmake script file that gets the values as command line parameters. This allows you to use the scripting commands allowing you do deal with empty lists.

**copy_script.cmake**

```
# inputs
#    FILES_TO_COPY
#    TARGET_DIR
if (FILES_TO_COPY)
    file(COPY ${FILES_TO_COPY} DESTINATION ${TARGET_DIR})
endif()
```

```
if (WIN32)

  add_custom_command(TARGET MyExe POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D "FILES_TO_COPY=$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:MyExe>" -D "TARGET_DIR=$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyExe>" -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_script.cmake"
  )
endif()
```